# How to share destructured variables from different React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, apollo-client, destructuring

How to share destructured variables from different React Hooks?

I have several in the same page:

```
const { loadingDogs, errorDogs, dataDogs } = useQuery(GET_DOGS);
const { loadingCats, errorCats, dataCats } = useQuery(GET_CATS);
...
```

Is it possible to use the same variable for `loading` and `error` in order to have a centralized management of a spinnig image?

Comment: Probably not in the same line. Try `const loading = { dogs: loadingDogs };` and `const error = { dogs: errorDogs }`?

Comment: Are `loadingDogs`, `errorDogs`, etc. the real keys in the returned object? Or does each query return a `{ loading, error, data }` and you're just not sure how to structure the logic?

Comment: @chazsolo The latter. That's what Apollo's `useQuery` returns

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there's a more clever way to do this with Apollo, but absent that, you could do this:

```
const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => { 
  setLoading(loadingDogs || loadingCats);
},[loadingDogs, loadingCats]);
```

Not sure what format the errors are in, but it would be something like:

```
const [errors, setErrors] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => { 
  setErrors(/* merge the errors here */);
},[errorCats, errorDogs]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rename destructured object properties 'like so.

```js
const { loading: loadingDogs, error: dogsError, data: dogData } = useQuery(GET_DOGS);
const { loading: loadingCats, error: catsError, data: catData } = useQuery(GET_CATS);
```